Prove that A is connected
I was given the following question: Show that if $A \subseteq X$ is such that $\forall x,y \in A$ there exists a connected set $C(x,y) \subseteq A$ with $x, y \in C(x,y)$, then A is connected.
I give the following solution: If $C(x,y)$ is connected, then the map $f: A \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ gives $f(C(x,y))=C_{x,y}$ where $C_{x,y}$ is a constant. Since there exists a $C(x,y) \text{ for all } x,y \in A$, then there will always exist a $z \in A$ such that $C(x,z)$ is a set in $A$. Because $x \in C(x,y) \cap C(x,z)$, it must be that $C_{x,y} = C_{x,z}$. Since $C(x,y)$ and $z$ are arbitrary, then $C_{x,y}$ is the same constant for all $x, y \in A$. Hence, $f(A)$ is also constant, and therefore connected.
My doubt stems from my argument claiming that "Since $C(x,y)$ and $z$ are arbitrary ..." Does it tie together well with the rest of statements? Does it make sense? I believe everything else is correct, but it may not be so. Any feedback is appreciated!

The idea you have is quite right. You have to be more careful: start with a \textit{continuous} map $f:A \longrightarrow {0,1}$, then as you explain, such map as to be constant.  Given this, $A$ must be connected since otherwise you can send \textit{continuously} a connected component in $0$ and another in $1$.

@AleK3 If I understand correctly, the main problem is not mentioning that the map $f$ is continuous?

Yes, more precisely (as the answer already tells you) instead of "the map $f:A \longrightarrow {0,1}$..." you should write "any continuous map $f:A \longrightarrow {0,1}$...

Your proof idea is great. Let me suggest some words.
A space $A$ is connected if and only if every continuous map $f:A\to\{0,1\}$ is constant. So let $f$ be such a map, and consider any two $x,y\in A$. By considering $C(x,y)$, we may see that $f(x)=f(y)$ (why?), showing that $f$ is constant on $A$, and thus $A$ is connected.
